# Help find what causes MBP reboot in 10.10.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

I have a Mac Book Pro from 2011. I've been updating it to all OSX versions since I bought it and recently I updated to Yosemite. At the time I also changed memory + HDD. I cloned my old drive to the new and swapped them.

Everything worked fine for 2 months but in the last 2 weeks I've had it crashing on me twice. It has never happened before.

Do you have any tips for how I can find what's causing the problem? I've been trying to look in the system.log file but I'm not sure what to look for. There is a lot of output there that doesn't feel quite right though...

Or should I just make my first re-install since I bought instead?

Thanks in advance for all help that can  point me in the right direction.

The system diagnostics report that I think is from the last crash can be seen here: http://olalindberg.com/static/2015/2015-02-19-mbp-sys-diag.txt

This error might be related as well. I see this a lot in the log and iTunes were running  at both crashes.

```
20/02/15 08:05:17,698 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.MediaLibrary Service.491) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.MediaLibraryService.xpc
```

No Idea what it means and Google didn't turn up much?

Update:

This error might be related as well. I see this a lot in the log and iTunes were running  at both crashes.

```
20/02/15 08:05:17,698 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.MediaLibrary Service.491) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.MediaLibraryService.xpc
```

No Idea what it means and Google didn't turn up much?

Update 2015-04-27: I've not had one crash and I have done a memory test to ensure that my memory wasn't the problem. I've also updated all my applications and my NTFS disk driver. Not sure if that helped at all though :)

Comment: Quick browse of the syst crash report shows your Google Chrome problems. Make sure you disable it completely (in Activity monitor) and test without it for a while.

Comment: Is it crashing when playing flash videos or using graphics heavy app like Photoshop ? Or is it crashing when boot ?

Comment: How do you mean with disable it completely in Activity monitor?

The computer works fine but it did hang twice in 2 weeks now and it never did before.

I think I found an issue that looks like mine in Chromium: http://goo.gl/xTJcXx

Comment: And here is one issue more similar to mine https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452894

Comment: I've not had any more reboots since this :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your Google Chrome on automatic updates, yours is the latest update version 40.0.2214.111

Why Chrome?

You crash report shows it as having problems causing other problems.

That should not crash your system, but only Chrome it self, but who knows.

What can you do?

Disable Chrome (for now) till Google comes up with a fix, and use another browser.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't crash the system... And I'm not sure it was chrome that crashed it... Both times I had iTunes up and running + 5 chrome windows + brackets. I sat and wrote some HTML/CSS when it suddenly hung. Any ideas?

Comment: And yes I have chrome on auto update